After 3 months, starter has never risen more than an inch
First time trying to make sourdough starter.  It has never risen more than 1/8 of the size (never doubled) after 3 months of feeding. I started off with whole wheat then all purpose flour.  Use purified water. 1:1:1 every 24 hrs. Tried using 1/2 rye flour with 1/2 all purpose.  It doesn't smell bad and has bubbles. No hooch and color is white. Tried keeping it in the garage where it's warmer.  Tried keeping in oven with light on. It's been 3 months. Should I give up??

So for clarification: you do see some rise and there’s no off smell? Have you tried using it or done a float test at some point?

The degree to which sourdough starter expands depends strongly on hydration (a wetter starter will release the gas, not foam up with it) and substrate (rye flour can’t hold the gas as well as white [wheat] flour) and to a lesser extent on temperature, feeding schedule, and the culture itself. I would not necessarily expect a healthy 100% hydration starter to have doubled in size at the end of 24 hours, nor would I use expansion to assess the health of a starter.
If it tastes active and sour, it’s ready to use.
